# System.Math.Round call works in one class, but is ambigous in the other

Tags: c#

Is this some bug in VS2022 or I'm missed something?

There is no problem with `RoundPoint` method this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Editor.View.Controls
{
    public partial class Workspace : UserControl
    {
        public Workspace() => InitializeComponent();

        // ... some other methods

        public Point RoundPoint(Point p, int r)
        {
             return new Point(Math.Round(p.X / r) * r, Math.Round(p.Y / r) * r);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I move `RoundPoint` method to the other class (which is static or not, it doesn't matter):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Editor.View.Controls
{
    public static class UiHelpers
    {
        public static Point RoundPoint(Point p, int r)
        {
            return new Point(Math.Round(p.X / r) * r, Math.Round(p.Y / r) * r);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

It throws this error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
> 'Math.Round(decimal)' and
> 'Math.Round(double)'  Editor\View\Controls\UiHelpers.cs

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I just realized that. Thank you for pointing out how they differ, if you add that as answer I will accept it.

Comment: Which `Point` do you actually want? `System.Windows.Point` or `System.Drawing.Point` or `System.Drawing.PointF`?

Comment: I'm working with `System.Windows.Point`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code file has a `using System.Drawing`, which means that `Point` refers to `System.Drawing.Point`. This uses `int` not `double`, so it doesn't make sense to round it (don't forget there is integer division, which means the result of the division is still an `int`).

Either cast one side of the division to `double` or `decimal`, or use `System.Drawing.PointF`.

Or perhaps you are just using the wrong library altogether, as noted in @Kamil's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question.

So I just realized that I was using two diffrent `Point` structs in .NET.

One is here:

```
System.Windows.Point
```

and the other is

```
System.Drawing.Point
```

Comment: That doesn't help by itself. The difference is the first uses `double` the latter `int`

Comment: But in dotnet core, there is only a Point in `System.Drawing`

Comment: @Luuk Not sure what you mean https://dotnetfiddle.net/M3DhIu. It is a separate library now, not part of the standard framework, but all the types are still there

Comment: @Charlieface: I was talking about this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/johSIt

Comment: @Luuk That's WPF (`System.Windows`), not Winforms and GDI (`System.Drawing`). The point is that they are two different libraries, that's exactly what this answer is trying to say.

Comment: "trying to say" there is where I went wrong (or my knowledge about ".NET Framework" vs. ".NET Core" is failing)